# Gurobi OR Constraint and Inequality Constraint in Python

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I'm implementing an OR logic with Gurobi. Specifically, I have two decision variables $x$ and $y$ and I want $x \neq y$. However, Gurobi doesn't support inequalities. So I tried to use OR logic like $x >= y + \epsilon OR y >= x + \epsilon$.

I've read the documentation of Gurobi and found they have the [addGenConstrOr()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_agc_or.html#pythonmethod:Model.addGenConstrOr) function. I tried to implement it according to the example usage `model.addGenConstrOr((z, [x>=y+\epsilon, y>=x+\epsilon], "orconstr")`. However, the program returned an error `gurobipy.Model.addGenConstrOr gurobipy.GurobiError: Invalid data in vars array`. It seems the data in the vars array of this function needs to be binary boolean variables. So my question is how to change this `x>=y+\epsilon` into a boolean variable such that I can fit this into the `model.addGenConstrOr` function? Or is there any better method to implement the inequality constraint in Gurobi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the variables `x` and `y` are continuous variables. `addGenConstrOr` is for binary variables so that is not immediately applicable.

Indeed, you can write `x ≠ y` as:

```
x ≤ y - ε OR x ≥ y + ε
```

There are different ways to implement this: (1) using binary variables, (2) using indicator constraints, and (3) using SOS1 sets. As you did not provide information on bounds on `x` and `y`, let's assume they are not available. In that case, indicator constraints are a good candidate:

```
 δ = 0 =>  x ≤ y - ε
 δ = 1 =>  x ≥ y + ε 
 δ ∈ {0,1}
```

See: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm wondering how can I write the "delta \in {0,1}" constraint in Gurobi. Or is it true that the first two constraints is enough for an OR relation?  But I guess in that case I need to specify \delta is a binary variable somewhere?

Comment: Obviously that is notation for a binary variable.